# Is that possible to create manually disable/enable vibrate setting for incoming APN from payload or from inside App?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, payload, iphone-vibrate

I need setting in my app for Enable/Disable vibrate for incoming APN regardless of sound.

It should not depend on sound.

May i control this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is no way to switch off vibration using open API from Apple. Only possible way is to disable it with alert sound, sending key for not existing sound file

Comment: @IvanAndrosenko, What if i want to play sound without vibration?

Comment: i think it's impossible as Apple doesn't like people handle such things in the app side